# Compiling old Carbon application on new OSX

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, macos-carbon

We have an old application completely based on Carbon API. It is huge and could take a while to make a conversion to Cocoa. I tried to compile the application with XCode 8.2.1 using SDK 10.4, but I always got this error:
malformed mach-o, symbol table not in __LINKEDIT

It seem that this SDK is not compatible with XCode 8. SDK 10.4 is coming from https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs

Q1: There is a way to compile old Carbon application with XCode 8?
Q2: It can be an option to install a Mac with old XCode and old OSX (10.6?)  to build this application?
Q3: Any other idea?

Thank you so much!

David

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing SDKs through [XcodeLegacy](https://github.com/devernay/xcodelegacy)? It seems better supported, and might do some extra steps besides just copying in the SDK.

Can it build with the 10.6 SDK, or do you need 10.4? I used to use the 10.6 SDK with Xcode 7 successfully, haven't used 10.4 though.

VMware Fusion can virtualize OS X versions back to 10.5, although Apple's license agreement (enforced by VMware) only allows 10.5 and 10.6 server versions to run.

You should definitely be able to build your app in Snow Leopard (either a VM or an old Mac)

Comment: Thanks for replying! Finally, I did install an iMac with OSX 10.6 and XCode 3.2.6, and everything is working well now (legacy SDK 10.4 is supported by XCode 3). Also, I did realized that OSX 10.7 contains GCC 4.2 only, which is not compatible with SDK 10.4.